# importing repos to github from curl results in 404 response

Tags: github, curl, import

i am trying to use the curl command for github importer to import repositories from tfs (as git), following [github's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/migrations/source-imports#:%7E:text=octocat/socm%22%0A%7D-,Start%20an%20import,-Works%20with%20GitHub)
when i am running this command, i get a 404 response:

```
curl \
-X PUT \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"\
-H "Authorization: token {MY_GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
https://api.github.com/repos/{MY-ORGANIZATION}/{REPO_NAME}/import \
-d '{"vcs":"git","vcs_url":"{TFS_REPO_URL}","vcs_username":"{TFS_USER_NAME}","vcs_password":"{TFS_PAT"}'
```

when i run the importer from the ui in github, everything works.

when i run a curl command to check the import status (for the repo i imported from the ui), i get a valid response:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: token {MY_GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/{MY-ORGANIZATION}/{REPO_NAME}/import
```

what is the missing piece?

Answer (score 0):

so apparently the importer works differently from the ui and from the api:
when running the importer from curl we first need to [create a repo in github](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository) and only then we can import it.